# Launch broadcast if disclaimer accepted but not before

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app which will use a broadcast receiver which will start when the phone is turned on.

However, when the user first installs and runs the app I want them to have to accept a disclaimer before the broadcast will do what it is designed to do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this.

Everytime BOOT_COMPLETED is recieved you can check for this preference. Only if it is true then continue.

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't know I could access SharedPreferences from a broadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sql at all? If so you can have a table for user preferences and have a field for "disclaimeraccepted" and set the value to 0..check the sql table when your broadcast receiver receives a message